# Hibernate doesn't create foreign keys in database for unidirectional ManyToOne

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two entities

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private City city;
}

@Entity
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "city_id")
    private int id;
}
```

[image]

Hibernate print in console that there was created foreign key to City table

```
Hibernate: alter table Address add constraint FKpwa35mv5w9mb3syngd4m8fprw foreign key (city_id) references City (city_id)
```

, but I can't see on database

Thx.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli MySQL

Comment: And you have refreshed the tables in the UI SQL editor.

Comment: Sure and also run sql script that shows foreign keys

Comment: and you are on the right database? Sorry to ask but when Hibernate prints this statement it also executes it. And have you tried to run this statement by your own?

Comment: And do you have InnoDB or MyISAM? MyISAM does not support foreign keys.

Comment: @Simon Martinelli, you're right, thank you. I see there is MyISAM.

Comment: Ok I will add that as the answer. If you would be so kind to select it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably use MyISAM as storage.
MyISAM does not support foreign keys.